# The operating system I use is Ubuntu version 13.04. How do we upgrade it to Ubuntu version 13.10?

Tags: upgrade

The operating system I use is Ubuntu version 13.04. How do we upgrade it to Ubuntu version 13.10 ?

Comment: Actually, you need to go to 14.04. 13.10 is also EOL. 14.04 is LTS http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: One addition to Tim's comment: you indeed have to upgrade to 14.04, but in order to do that you'll have to upgrade to 13.10 first.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a terminal and write this commmand: **update-manager -d**

Update Manager now will open and you can upgrade to 13.10... :)

Comment: Downvote: Without using old-releases mirror as shown in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) this will only give errors.